# Passing Two Selectors via Router-Outlet to two Ng-Content

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular4-router

I want to pass two selectors via a router-outlet and further wants to add two ng content for the router outlet. below is my code:

**dashboard.html**

```
  <div class="row" body>
       <p> I am body </p>
  </div>
```

**pages.html**

```
<app-layout> 
        <button header type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                Single Button
        </button>   
    <router-outlet body></router-outlet>
</app-layout>
```

**layout.html**

```
<div class="panel panel-white">
      <div class="panel-heading">
         <ngx-pageheader>
              <ng-content select="[header]"></ng-content>
          </ngx-pageheader>
         <div class="clearfix"></div>
       </div>

       <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="portlet box portlet-blue">
              <div class="portlet-body">
                  <ng-content select="[body]"></ng-content>
               </div>
           </div>

</div>
```

The above code wroks perfectly like I want, button sets up in header body sets up in header in ng content, but what i need now is moving the button code in dashboard.html and populate the contents accordingly.